# Unique Function based on 2 columns [Instead of rows] <<Cell Array>> Matlab

Tags: matlab, unique

I have a cell array, `a`, with contents as follows:

```
a{1}=[1 3 4 5;
      3 3 4 5;
      5 5 4 5;
      2 4 2 6;
      6 5 2 6;
      7 2 3 1;]
```

How can I apply the `unique` function on 2 columns [column 3 and 4] such that they will return the value '3' and '2'. [Since there are 3 duplicates for the pair 4,5 and 2 duplicates for the pair 2,6.]

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
[B,I,J] = unique(a{1}(:,[3,4]),'rows');
N = hist(J,numel(unique(J)));
N(N~=1)
```

This would give you:

```
ans =

     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
desiredCol=3;
B=unique(a{1}(:,desiredCol));
count=histc(a{1}(:,desiredCol),B);
desiredMat(:,2)= count(count~=1);
multipleOccElm= (count~=1).*B;
desiredMat(:,1)=multipleOccElm(multipleOccElm~=0);
```

This is how you interpret `desiredMat`:

Take the first row for example. first column will contain the element. Second column will contain how many times it occurred in that particular column. Note that single occurrences will not be displayed.

For the 4th column this is how `desiredMat` looks:

```
desiredMat =

     5     3
     6     2
```